# How to show more fields on custom object tabs in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Ok so this problem is probably easily solvable, but since I am a beginner in Salesforce and I didn't find anything useful on Google, I am asking if someone can please help me.

So, as you can see, I have created a custom object called Students, and added some fields to it.
[image]

Next, I have created a custom object tab, called Student, as you can see on the following image and added some records.
[image]

On the custom object tab, only field 'Student Name' is shown. Does anybody know how to display all (or some) of the fields that were added to the object Student?

Thank you so much for your answers and have a great day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the far right of the 2nd screenshot there's a gear/cog icon. Use it for o create new "list view". Or click that "recently viewed", change it to "all" (there should be an auto-generated one for you) and use that gear icon to select which fields to display.

You can even pin the list view to be your default if you don't want "recently viewed".

As for recently viewed itself - it's special, the gear icon won't work. Follow this article: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_recent_records_list_lex.htm&type=5

Comment: you are correct, i dont know why I havent found this anywhere on the internet haha, thank you :)

Comment: it's easy when you know what to google for. you'll get there :)